# keycloak spring boot is always giving Didn't find publicKey for specified kid

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to solve the issue "Didn't find publicKey for specified kid". Can someone please suggest possibly mistakes here. the problem is preflight request goes through but somehow it tries to authenticate my request even though I have logged in and though bearerdetails are present in header it still says failed to authenticate.

**Spring Security Configuration:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@KeycloakConfiguration
// @ConditionalOnProperty(name = "keycloak.enabled", havingValue = "true", matchIfMissing = true)
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = KeycloakSecurityComponents.class)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(jsr250Enabled = true)
public class SpringKeycloakSecurityConfiguration extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .permitAll();
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(new SimpleAuthorityMapper());
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }

    @Bean
    public KeycloakConfigResolver KeycloakConfigResolver() {
        return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
    }
```

**Response from backend:**

```
STATUS: 401 Unauthorized
HEADERS
cache-control:
private
connection:
keep-alive
content-length:
0
date:
Wed, 04 Aug 2021 03:00:58 GMT
expires:
Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
keep-alive:
timeout=60
www-authenticate:
Bearer realm="xxx.com", error="invalid_token", error_description="Didn't find publicKey for specified kid"
```

**Backend logs:**

```
2021-08-03 09:48:43.706 DEBUG 6840 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer      : Received [GET /2021-07-14/ui/uiobject?locale=en-US HTTP/1.1
host: localhost:8080
proxy-connection: keep-alive
sec-ch-ua: " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="91", "Chromium";v="91"
accept: */*
authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCIgOiAiSldUIiwia2lkIiA6ICJOUnBIMm1LSjU4aWkwUHYyMkpWOHczWjVvX2ZXT1JvV0g0RGFXSFY4UU04In0.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.JVjLkSr5nAyLGyB3pBm9PnR0IJnhLROGeXiunphJa-avU_Bo-k-xmqcNKVHShF6YSWk1Ou36TlmNKIh3igTfhS4cPObGsnjxCLGrkYLELOxhpLVeB3Cqqn7Goy3LSjuuXJMtrPa4RcDuA3e8ltrjdoxcPFzQ0qLMlp_hk014gX8jendDPwDqcAbxy098Ptc5aNGV1gWSJtff65U_eIrWwWPRp8ow9Qd_jIilgmmi-AubC8ftFDXbmEoolOS_2sO6_FGCoyV4kEjf5orsj3e5Ucv3kK2Ie1lAz39IJYyrk0Txq974tMVwVbWA3lLPsfx0AecZrvJrPAOIDS2KmwmvWg
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36
tenant: xxx.com
origin: http://localhost:3000
sec-fetch-site: same-site
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-dest: empty
referer: http://localhost:3000/
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive

]

2021-08-03 09:48:43.711 DEBUG 6840 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.k.adapters.PreAuthActionsHandler       : adminRequest http://localhost:8080/2021-07-14/ui/uiobject?locale=en-US
2021-08-03 09:48:43.711 DEBUG 6840 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.k.adapters.PreAuthActionsHandler       : checkCorsPreflight http://localhost:8080/2021-07-14/ui/uiobject?locale=en-US
2021-08-03 09:48:43.712 DEBUG 6840 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.c.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase    : Security checking request GET /2021-07-14/ui/uiobject
2021-08-03 09:48:43.712 DEBUG 6840 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase      :   Checking constraint 'SecurityConstraint[UiEndpoints]' against GET /ui/uiobject --> true
2021-08-03 09:48:43.712 DEBUG 6840 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase      :   Checking constraint 'SecurityConstraint[UiEndpoints]' against GET /ui/uiobject --> true
2021-08-03 09:48:43.712 DEBUG 6840 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.c.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase    : Calling hasUserDataPermission()
2021-08-03 09:48:43.712 DEBUG 6840 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase      :   User data constraint has no restrictions
2021-08-03 09:48:43.714 DEBUG 6840 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.c.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase    : Calling authenticate()
2021-08-03 09:48:43.714 DEBUG 6840 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.k.a.BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator    : Found [1] values in authorization header, selecting the first value for Bearer.
2021-08-03 09:48:43.715 DEBUG 6840 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.k.a.BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator    : Verifying access_token
2021-08-03 09:48:43.717 DEBUG 6840 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.h.i.c.t.ThreadSafeClientConnManager  : Get connection: {s}->https://authentication.xxx.com:443, timeout = 0
2021-08-03 09:48:43.717 DEBUG 6840 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.h.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute    : [{s}->https://authentication.xxx.com:443] total kept alive: 1, total issued: 0, total allocated: 1 out of 20
2021-08-03 09:48:43.717 DEBUG 6840 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.h.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute    : Getting free connection [{s}->https://authentication.xxx.com:443][null]
2021-08-03 09:48:43.717 DEBUG 6840 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient   : Stale connection check
2021-08-03 09:48:43.723 DEBUG 6840 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient   : Stale connection detected
2021-08-03 09:48:43.724 DEBUG 6840 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.h.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection  : Connection 0.0.0.0:52467<->52.200.236.105:443 closed
2021-08-03 09:48:43.779 DEBUG 6840 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] .a.h.i.c.DefaultClientConnectionOperator : Connecting to authentication.xxx.com:443
2021-08-03 09:48:43.953 DEBUG 6840 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] jdk.event.security                       : ValidationChain: -1472444962, -1011578998, -2069289871
2021-08-03 09:48:44.144 DEBUG 6840 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] jdk.event.security                       :  TLSHandshake: authentication.xxx.com:443, TLSv1.2, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, -2069289871
2021-08-03 09:48:44.145 DEBUG 6840 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.h.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies  : CookieSpec selected: compatibility
2021-08-03 09:48:44.145 DEBUG 6840 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.h.client.protocol.RequestAuthCache   : Auth cache not set in the context
2021-08-03 09:48:44.145 DEBUG 6840 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.h.c.p.RequestTargetAuthentication    : Target auth state: UNCHALLENGED
2021-08-03 09:48:44.145 DEBUG 6840 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.h.c.p.RequestProxyAuthentication     : Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
2021-08-03 09:48:44.145 DEBUG 6840 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient   : Attempt 1 to execute request
2021-08-03 09:48:44.145 DEBUG 6840 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.h.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection  : Sending request: GET /auth/realms/xxx.com/protocol/openid-connect/certs HTTP/1.1
2021-08-03 09:48:44.145 DEBUG 6840 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.http.wire                     :  >> "GET /auth/realms/xxx.com/protocol/openid-connect/certs HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
2021-08-03 09:48:44.146 DEBUG 6840 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.http.wire                     :  >> "Host: authentication.xxx.com[\r][\n]"
2021-08-03 09:48:44.146 DEBUG 6840 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.http.wire                     :  >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
2021-08-03 09:48:44.146 DEBUG 6840 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.http.wire                     :  >> "[\r][\n]"
2021-08-03 09:48:44.146 DEBUG 6840 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.http.headers                  : >> GET /auth/realms/xxx.com/protocol/openid-connect/certs HTTP/1.1
2021-08-03 09:48:44.146 DEBUG 6840 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.http.headers                  : >> Host: authentication.xxx.com
2021-08-03 09:48:44.146 DEBUG 6840 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.http.headers                  : >> Connection: Keep-Alive
2021-08-03 09:48:44.217 DEBUG 6840 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.http.wire                     :  << "HTTP/1.1 200 OK[\r][\n]"
2021-08-03 09:48:44.217 DEBUG 6840 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.http.wire                     :  << "Date: Tue, 03 Aug 2021 16:48:43 GMT[\r][\n]"
2021-08-03 09:48:44.217 DEBUG 6840 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.http.wire                     :  << "Content-Type: application/json[\r][\n]"
2021-08-03 09:48:44.219 DEBUG 6840 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.http.wire                     :  << "Content-Length: 1478[\r][\n]"
2021-08-03 09:48:44.219 DEBUG 6840 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.http.wire                     :  << "Connection: keep-alive[\r][\n]"
2021-08-03 09:48:44.219 DEBUG 6840 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.http.wire                     :  << "Cache-Control: no-cache[\r][\n]"
2021-08-03 09:48:44.219 DEBUG 6840 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.http.wire                     :  << "X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block[\r][\n]"
2021-08-03 09:48:44.219 DEBUG 6840 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.http.wire                     :  << "X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN[\r][\n]"
2021-08-03 09:48:44.219 DEBUG 6840 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.http.wire                     :  << "Referrer-Policy: no-referrer[\r][\n]"
2021-08-03 09:48:44.219 DEBUG 6840 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.http.wire                     :  << "Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains[\r][\n]"
2021-08-03 09:48:44.219 DEBUG 6840 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.http.wire                     :  << "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff[\r][\n]"
2021-08-03 09:48:44.219 DEBUG 6840 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.http.wire                     :  << "[\r][\n]"
2021-08-03 09:48:44.219 DEBUG 6840 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.h.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection  : Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
2021-08-03 09:48:44.219 DEBUG 6840 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.http.headers                  : << HTTP/1.1 200 OK
2021-08-03 09:48:44.219 DEBUG 6840 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.http.headers                  : << Date: Tue, 03 Aug 2021 16:48:43 GMT
2021-08-03 09:48:44.219 DEBUG 6840 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.http.headers                  : << Content-Type: application/json
2021-08-03 09:48:44.219 DEBUG 6840 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.http.headers                  : << Content-Length: 1478
2021-08-03 09:48:44.219 DEBUG 6840 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.http.headers                  : << Connection: keep-alive
2021-08-03 09:48:44.219 DEBUG 6840 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.http.headers                  : << Cache-Control: no-cache
2021-08-03 09:48:44.219 DEBUG 6840 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.http.headers                  : << X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
2021-08-03 09:48:44.219 DEBUG 6840 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.http.headers                  : << X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
2021-08-03 09:48:44.219 DEBUG 6840 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.http.headers                  : << Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
2021-08-03 09:48:44.219 DEBUG 6840 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.http.headers                  : << Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
2021-08-03 09:48:44.219 DEBUG 6840 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.http.headers                  : << X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
2021-08-03 09:48:44.220 DEBUG 6840 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient   : Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
2021-08-03 09:48:44.220 DEBUG 6840 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] org.apache.http.wire                     :  << "{"keys":[{"kid":"ZT0YsuS7Lgsh37eN3WVVPrIL7Kb3qRz_lMwAtLHfYDY","kty":"RSA","alg":"RS256","use":"sig","n":"s-FCK6-rgMANfL2JIEB4kEL5i6zW3IIxFN_PTyWmpdopDX9ptjVoFesp34FV5jpz1oYrssn9y_IFhKTpBuqqV7g65eHap0HeUIO5InKI7HL5hRmbrxYTJoOnoOQnQte6pvTdAc313GExRg3zAT_MM_iawyqRrVq9kfcdcpNe5qIyKNlt_pyPvvIM5rNKOd4L8Bt1zYPK1Nik1JPKmJLkXugHjn4SdDRaCRT1k2zcomx4ZUPtHBfajXgKK1rxbNZnFK8E8IAZGAUGHOFQFbFMdKYqRLrkgg4tZTcYHaGdL9Wx6n8_uQjTGmCRCvsQfGtlSPVSPMKnCEK6HkeHg0RG-Q","e":"AQAB","x5c":["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"],"x5t":"j3eCSy2GZJuewVR9a_Tz0u5fdeU","x5t#S256":"Q3KrFXwqJWv0xSrba9g2XqNwxM2hMPDKkUvJRieu3LA"}]}"
2021-08-03 09:48:44.221 DEBUG 6840 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.h.i.c.t.ThreadSafeClientConnManager  : Released connection is reusable.
2021-08-03 09:48:44.221 DEBUG 6840 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.h.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute    : Releasing connection [{s}->https://authentication.xxx.com:443][null]
2021-08-03 09:48:44.221 DEBUG 6840 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.h.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute    : Pooling connection [{s}->https://authentication.xxx.com:443][null]; keep alive indefinitely
2021-08-03 09:48:44.221 DEBUG 6840 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.h.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute    : Notifying no-one, there are no waiting threads
2021-08-03 09:48:44.221 DEBUG 6840 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.k.a.rotation.JWKPublicKeyLocator       : Realm public keys successfully retrieved for client xxx.com. New kids: [ZT0YsuS7Lgsh37eN3WVVPrIL7Kb3qRz_lMwAtLHfYDY]
2021-08-03 09:48:44.221 ERROR 6840 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.k.a.rotation.AdapterTokenVerifier      : Didn't find publicKey for kid: NRpH2mKJ58ii0Pv22JV8w3Z5o_fWORoWH4DaWHV8QM8
2021-08-03 09:48:44.221 DEBUG 6840 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.k.a.BearerTokenRequestAuthenticator    : Failed to verify token
2021-08-03 09:48:44.221 DEBUG 6840 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.k.adapters.RequestAuthenticator        : Bearer FAILED
2021-08-03 09:48:44.221 DEBUG 6840 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.a.c.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase    : Failed authenticate() test
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to this problem ->
keycloak server config I was using partially from local and partially from stage env. UI code had local server details of keycloak and backend server had stage server details.. JWT token from browser gave the clear picture on the same as it was not matching the server side config I had. That was resulting in authentication error.